# Force SASS to not calculate the content of a variable?

Tags: css, sass, grid, mixins, css-grid

me with this problem?

I've trying to use a mxin for grid-row and grid-column in this format:

```
@mixin grid-row($row){
    grid-row: $row;
    -ms-grid-row: $row;
}

@mixin grid-column($column){
    grid-column: $column;
    -ms-grid-column: $column;
}
```

But in case when I use values ​​like 1/3 the SASS calculate the value instead of printing the value directly.

The result in compiled css is:

```
grid-row: 0.3333333333;
-ms-grid-row: 0.3333333333;
grid-column: 0.3333333333;
-ms-grid-column: 0.3333333333;
```

Has a method to force SASS print this value diretamente (like a string)?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) just put the value like that `#{"value"}`

```
@mixin grid-row($row){
    grid-row: $row;
   -ms-grid-row: $row;
}

@mixin grid-column($column){
    grid-column: $column;
    -ms-grid-column: $column;
}

.item {
  @include grid-row(#{"1/3"});
  @include grid-column(#{"1/2"});
}
```

result will be like that

```
.item {
  grid-row: 1/3;
  -ms-grid-row: 1/3;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  -ms-grid-column: 1/2;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the much more elegant answer which produces much more readable Code. To stop SASS calculation you just have to mask it. Instead of `grid-column: 2 / -1;` just write `grid-column: #{'2 / -1'};`.

Answer (score 0):

For now I did it that way and it worked fine:

```
@mixin grid-row ($init, $end: null) {

    @if ($end) {
        grid-row: #{$init + " / " + $end};
        -ms-grid-row: #{$init + " / " + $ end};
    }

    @else {
        grid-row: $init;
        -ms-grid-row: $init;
    }

}

@mixin grid-column ($init, $end: null) {
    @if ($end) {
        grid-column: #{$ init + " / " + $end};
        -ms-grid-column: #{$init + " / " + $end};
    }

    @else {
        grid-column: $init;
        -ms-grid-column: $init;
    }
}
```

I would still like to know if there is a way to force SASS do not calculate content of variables.

Thanks!